# Horizontal scroll event based on pixel distance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if someone can help me create an event for whether a user is within, say 100px, from the left side of a screen and then output an alert message (for testing purposes).

I appreciate any assistance in this regard, many thanks in advance!

Comment: What user action do you expect? Click, mouseover, etc?

Comment: @antyrat, scroll action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a scroll listener to DOM elements, for example in jQuery:

```
$('#someelement').scroll(function() {

     // do something
})
```

See [here.](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Also, you can get the scroll distance; again in jQuery:

```
$('#someelement').scrollLeft()
```

See [here.](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

Combine these to implement the desired behavior.